# Space manager is invalid on APFS volume inside sparebundle on NAS

Tags: backup, time-machine, nas

I cannot get the sparsebundle to mount on my synology NAS drive, the error returned suggests that it's corrupted. I have re-installed macOS and I'm looking to restore the files from the backup. Migration assistant failed with the error that no volumes could be found, and when I inspect the volume it appears to be corrupt.

What to do from here?

```
Last login: Sat Apr 23 17:28:55 on ttys000
glen@Glens-Mac-mini ~ % chflags -R nouchg /Volumes/Time\ Machine\ Glen\ Mac\ Mini/Mac\ mini.sparsebundle
glen@Glens-Mac-mini ~ % sudo su -
Password:
Glens-Mac-mini:~ root# hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck /Volumes/Time\ Machine\ Glen\ Mac\ Mini/Mac\ mini.sparsebundle/
/dev/disk4              GUID_partition_scheme           
/dev/disk4s1            EFI                             
/dev/disk4s2            Apple_APFS                      
/dev/disk5              EF57347C-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 
/dev/disk5s1            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 
Glens-Mac-mini:~ root# fsck_apfs -dfy /dev/disk4s2
warning: option -f is not implemented, ignoring
Requested cache size: 2048MB (32k blocks * 64kB)
** Checking the container superblock.
   Checking the checkpoint with transaction ID 327871.
** Checking the space manager.
warning: (oid 0x73ab) cib: invalid o_cksum (0xffffffffffffffff)
error: failed to read spaceman cib 1 at address 0x73ab
   Space manager is invalid.
** The container /dev/disk4s2 could not be verified completely.
Glens-Mac-mini:~ root#
```